# replaceWith before submit

Tags: jquery

I am forced to have to replace the tags with `<br> <br/>` as I pass it to a xml parser and without proper tags raises an exception.

I've tried this before a submit:

```
$('form#mail').submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".note-editable br").replaceWith('<br/>');
    $(this).submit();
});
```

but causes an error and does not fire submit:

```
Uncaught RangeError: Maximum call stack size exceeded
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an infinite loop here:

```
$(this).submit();
```

which points the script back to:

```
$('form#mail').submit(function(e){ ...
```

**Solution:**

```
$('form#mail').submit(function(e){
    //e.preventDefault(); - don't do this
    $(".note-editable br").replaceWith('<br/>');
    //$(this).submit(); - or this
});
```

If you are submitting a form you are sending the browser to another page, why then do you need to make DOM changes on the current page?

Answer (score 0):

You are looping through the function. You prevent the default submitting from happening, after which you submit the form again, which is again prevented.

You could do this:

```
$('input[type="submit"]').on('click', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".note-editable br").replaceWith('<br/>');
    $('form#mail').submit();
});
```